# A basic physical chemistry problem

Tags: elemental-analysis

I am a high school student and have just begin my classes(online). I just started physical chemistry but I know about moles, percentage composition, empirical formula. I haven't been able to solve this question and due to my inability to approach my teachers(most of the time they are busy recording lectures), I post my question here.

In particular I am confused by that silver chloride line.

[image]

[image: here are my notes]

Comment: The idea here would be that any chlorine in the sample reacts to form silver chloride. Use stoichiometry to back calculate how much chlorine was in the sample.

Comment: I  have not done that much, please post an elaborate answer

Comment: You haven't provided enough details to effectively help you. Where are you stuck? Can you show some work? Do you have a book where you can look at examples of determining empirical formula?

Comment: A basic tenet of Stack Exchange is to have the questions and answers succinct that others can search for and answer questions. However your title is generic and your question is an image which is not searchable.

Comment: The example problem is not exactly the same as the problem you have. You need to use some stoichiometry to back compute the mass of the individual elements first. From there, you can try to determine the empirical formula, similar to what is done in the example.

Comment: @JordanLawson, There is a very famous reaction in which chloride ions are quantitatively precipitated by silver nitrate. 1 mol silver nitrate reacts with 1 mol chloride ion to form 1 mol silver chloride. This hint should help you to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use each of the emperical formulas given and produce a balanced complete combustion question for each one as well as working out the moles of each compound given. You already know how many moles of CO2 and water were produced because you were given weights. From there you can see which compound it is most likely to be because the moles of that compound should produce the moles of the products when the stoichiometry is taken into account.

As for the silver chloride: (Correction) You cannot directly react AgNO3 with organic solvents but when you convert the compound into a sodium salt and dissociate the chloride ions, the chloride ions will then react with the AgNO3 in a 1:1 molar ratio. So working out the moles of AgCl produced and comparing with the moles potentially produced from each compound will help you determine if there is one or two Cl atoms in the compound you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please make a correction? AgNO3 does not react with an organic compound which contains chlorine directly like chloroform or dichloromethane. AgNO3 is not even soluble in organic solvents or pure compounds. You have to heat an organic compound with sodium and then you make a solution of it. That solution is reacted with AgNO3.